# Where to find exact definition of I/P and O/P as used to define insulation resistance for AC DC converter?

Tags: ac-dc, insulation

Most AC DC converter datasheet use I/p and O/P to define insulation resistance

I am looking for the exact definition of these parameters as used in this context (I know their definition for transformer winding but an AC DC converter is more complicated).

The reason I am trying to better understand these parameters is that one of my current projects requires that I float the DC output with respect to the general ground.

Comment: AC to DC converters use transformers for isolation so, given that you know that definition for a transformer (because you said you did), you now know it for an AC to DC converter.

Comment: Of course but this  assumes that  there is no complications associated with the switching which is what I want to make sure of.

Comment: Why should the switching arrangement affect the transformer's isolation characteristic?

Comment: it wil not but when you read on an AC DC data sheet insulation strength  related to I/P and O/P I assume it is measured on the in and out of the converter ( this is what I am trying to confirm as a matter of fact) the transformer being just one component. On the other hand if the insulation properties is strictly the transformer one's, does that mean that  the converter as a whole will have the same insulation properties?

Comment: I/P mean in and O/P means out. How ambiguous can this be?

Comment: Remember everything on the input (for example) is more or less connected by conductors. If you raise one part of the input circuit to, for example, 5 kV, you're going to be raising every part of the input side to 5 kV. If there's a leakage path from anywhere on the input side, it's going to fail the insulation resistance test.